# mle2-class Weibull three-parameter probability density function plot

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, mle, weibull

I am fitting my data (wind data) to different distributions (two and three parameter weibull and gamma distributions). I used the method explained here (mle2 using "L-BFGS-B" method) to estimate the parameters of the three-parameter weibull distribution: [Weibull Distribution parameter estimation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55386447/weibull-distribution-parameter-estimation-error)
I used fitdist (from fitdistrplus library) to estimate the parameters of the two-weibull and gamma distribution. Now I want to compare the fit of the two-parameter weibull, three-parameter weibull and gamma distribution to my data on the same plot. I was able to compare the fit of two-parameter weibull and gamma but failed to include three-parameter weibull (it's a different class). Is it possible to plot the weibull two-parameter and three-parameter on the same plot. I would highly appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

estimating parameters of three-parameter and two-parameter weibull:

```
    library(bbmle)
    library(FAdist)

    y = my.data
    eps <- 1e-8
    weibull3 <- mle2(y ~ dweibull3(shape=shape, scale = scale, thres = thres), start=list(shape=1, scale=1, thres=-5),lower=c(shape=0,scale=0,thres=-Inf), upper=c(shape=Inf,scale=Inf,thres=min(y)-eps), method="L-BFGS-B", data=data.frame(y))

    weibull3
    call:

     mle2(minuslogl = y ~ dweibull3(shape = shape, scale = scale, thres = thres), start = list(shape = 1, scale = 1, thres = -5), method = "L-BFGS-B", data = data.frame(y), lower = c(shape = 0, scale = 0, thres = -Inf), upper = c(shape = Inf, scale = Inf, thres = min(y) - eps))

     coefficients:
      shape      scale      thre
    2.4828383  5.5248459 -0.2530033


    Log-likelihood: -1358214 


    library (fitdistrplus)
    weibull2 = fitdist(my.data, "weibull")
    weibull2

    Fitting of the distribution ' weibull ' by maximum likelihood 
       Parameters:
          estimate  Std. Error
    shape 2.324290 0.002344834
    scale 5.238753 0.002980665
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please format your code and don't mix it with comments.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. Okay.Let me make an edit. Thanks